# Create a LiveUSB from existing Ubuntu / Xubuntu installation?

Tags: xubuntu, virtualbox, live-usb

I have a Xubuntu in my VirtualBox machine with several changes, and I'd like to make a LiveUSB out of it.

I've already heard about Remastersys, but it's not supported anymore. [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) explains how to customize a LiveCD but it needs an ISO as a base, I can't use an existing installation.

`Relinux` also seems to be abandoned.

How can I create a Live USB from my Xubuntu installation?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~cubic-wizard is the tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you what you need is [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) which can backup the whole disk or only the selected partition (cant say it is a "Live CD/USB"). There are many tutorial available in the internet like [this](http://gamblisfx.com/how-to-clone-ubuntu-system-using-clonezilla/) one. There is also [Clonezilla live](http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php) that allows you to use CD/DVD or USB flash drive to boot and run clonezilla.

As alternatives you can try [Systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback) which will help you create live system (currently only works for Ubuntu derivatives based on 14.04, 14.10, and 15.04). To install this, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nemh/systemback
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemback
```

There is an excellent [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-live-system-iso-for-your-ubuntu-based-linux-machines-using-systemback/) on how to use Systemback.

There is also a tool called [Mondo Rescue](http://www.mondorescue.org/docs.shtml) which you can try.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a limitation of 4GB on the USB sticks, that's why I need an iso of a LiveUSB which would take around less than 2GB for system files + the rest of the space for persistent files.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question. It's not fair to Ron that you add constraints after the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you want as I am not a programmer but I think it my be worth a try doing this in two hits; 1) use a minimal install cd or usb with [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) and then install your packages with [Apt on CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/110034/how-to-back-up-restore-your-installed-ubuntu-packages-with-aptoncd/)?